# Meteor - Read HTML file contents and store in a variable

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteorite, spacebars, underscore.js-templating

I am a newbie to Meteor. In my earlier project (Front end: Plain JS), i used 'underscore' js library as templating engine. I would like to acheive the same in meteor. But i face problems in getting HTML file contents. Let's go with the scenario in older project,

In a JS file (myfilename.js.php)

```
var htmlstr = <?php echo jsonStringify('../templates/template-name.html'); ?>;
var myData = [{id: 1}, {id:2}];
$(selector).html(_.template(htmlstr, {data: myData }));
```

This will generate HTML string and append to the specific selector(either DIV/HTML... )

The Meteor also supports underscore JS. I would like to apply same thing and same methodology here.
I am struggling to achieve the first step(including html file content in a variable)

Could someone please help me in solving this.

Thank you.

Comment: Try reading documentation before just posting on stackoverflow
http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic

Comment: I would like to achieve this with underscore template library. Is it possible?

Comment: Sometimes when you you adopt a different technology, you have to adapt your thinking to use the tools as they were intended. It is possible to use underscore to do the templating but you will have trouble doing the rendering as you need a complete templating system for that, you have the Blaze templating engine to do that for you, or you can use React, either are excellent templating tools